# Excel: Get value from cell indirectly for an offset formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula looks like that:

```
=OFFSET(supergraph!$Q$15;0;0;1;15)
```

The formula works fine but now I want to get the value of a cell for the `supergraph!$Q$15` term.
In my cell I write for instance "X" and I want the term mentioned above to look like `supergraph!$X$15`, depending on the value of the cell. So in my cell i just write one single letter which should be combined with the number 15 -> *X15*.
Is it anyhow possible to extract the value from the cell and integrate it in my formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the INDIRECT formula in your OFFSET formula to achieve this like below:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(supergraph!$Q$15&3),1,0)
```

If you have "X" in **supergraph!$Q$15**, then the output will be `=OFFSET(X3,1,0)`